# Dealing with a few closed questions...Books, what makes a good tester etc.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In the first day there were several questions that were closed that I think should be reopened and probably set as community wiki.  One was about what makes up a good bug report, and what makes a good tester.  The good tester one was clearly noted as on on topic question as part of the definintion.  Yes - it will be somewhat subjective but I suspect there will be a fair amount of shared information.  I fully believe that questions like this have thier place on this site.  Thoughts?

Comment: Testing as a subject is on-topic, but that doesn't mean any question ever about testing is on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

I think they do have a place on this site - but I can see why they've been closed *at this stage*. They're pretty generic questions - if I hit the front page of the site and all I saw was that kind of question, I would probably assume there wasn't that much of interest for me here and move on. Once the site is better established, then I think re-opening those questions as community wiki would be fine - a lot of testing questions *don't* have one true answer - that's what makes testing challenging as a profession.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  Please everyone read through http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta again and please make sure you read the links in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Books, I'd say belong as "community wiki". The other one, probably is going to stay closed as argumentative and subjective.